# remote desktop connection WIN10->Ubuntu18.04 black screen

Tags: 18.04, windows-10, remote-desktop

I can not seem to use rdc from Win10 to connect to my Ubuntu box (on the same network). None of the suggestions have worked for me yet (disabling bitmap, changing resolution etc). It will connect but show nothing but black.

The steps I take are

1 ssh into Ubuntu box

2 start xrdp

3 start rdc on Win10 machine on same network

4 use default connection options and point it at the IP address of the Linux box

5 connection occurs and displays a black screen

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04(.6 if that matters), just checked. Desktop, definitely not headless

Comment: There is no `xrdc` in Ubuntu. There is, however, `xrdp`. Accurate details make your Question more likely to get better help. Remember that you can edit you own question to improve it. Your question should also explain the process you are following (we are not psychic). If you are following instructions, a link to those instructions would help a lot.

Comment: I attempted to address the concerns in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect from windows to linux using xrdp server
i recommand you to install bitve ssh client on your windows
then install xrdp in your linux
and if you click on new remote desktop connection
everything gets ok automaticly
this is a tested way and i have used it before

Comment: I can't install new software on my machine, it's IT limited.

Comment: then try vnc connection to your linux server , Xrdp does not work as good as windows on linux

Comment: Doesn't that require the VNC viewer download? I'm willing to try it, but can you give me a link to more information or a walkthrough?

Comment: i guess there is  some pre installed vnc viewer in your linux

Comment: I would need the viewer on my windows client though

Comment: there is some web controled versions of vnc
you can connect them using your browser

Comment: Can you link an example for this?